# "Add link" in my account menu

Tags: 7, routes, users

The user account page (http://example.com/user) consists of some default tabs like  "View," "Edit," etc.

I want to add my menu link over there. The content to be returned should depend on the user ID. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you want to display there? A View, a custom made page, a node, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add a new tab, then the module should just implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), using code similar to the following.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user/%user/new_tab'] = array(
    'title' => 'New tab title', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_newtab_form', 1), 
    'access arguments' => array('access new tab'), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_newtab_form($form, &$form_state, $account) {
  // ...
}
```

`mymodule_newtab_form()` would get the user object in `$account`. That menu callback would build a form using the form API. If the purpose is to output, the menu callback declaration would be similar, except two array indexes, which would be:

```
'page callback' => 'mymodule_newtab_form', 
'page arguments' => array(1),
```

The argument passed to the callback would be different too.